# Bad RawFormat when loading emf file

Tags: c#, image, .emf

I'm trying to load an emf file in to an Image Object, however the RawFormat is always incorrect {[ImageFormat: b96b3cac-0728-11d3-9d7b-0000f81ef32e]} instead of Emf. I've tried loading from a file stream and memory stream. I've also tried creating a MetaFile object instead of an Image but to no avail. Is this a bug or there some other trick I don't know about?

```
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(imageData);//imageData is a byte array
Image tempImage = Image.FromStream(stream);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this help?

System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Emf.Guid = {b96b3cac-0728-11d3-9d7b-0000f81ef32e}

Dan